# Python Selenium: How to click an element containing text and which parent is button

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have two buttons on a page containing "Einloggen" text and I need to click the "Einloggen" button.

The first element with "Probleme beim Einloggen?" is a link  with span.

[image]

[image]

and the second, which I need is a button with a span.

[image]

CSS classes are not stable, I cannot use them.

I have tried:

```
self.log_in_link = WebDriverWait(self.driver, self.delay).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//button/following-sibling::span[contains(text(), 'Einloggen')]")))
```

But it can't find it

If I try so

```
self.log_in_link = WebDriverWait(self.driver, self.delay).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, ".//span[contains(text(), 'Einloggen')]")))
```

The driver clicks the wrong element ("Probleme beim Einloggen?")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the picture you presented I see the parent element here is not a `button` rather `div` with `buttonstyle` class.
Please try this XPath

```py
//div[contains(@class,'buttonstyle')]//span[contains(text(),'Einloggen')]
```

I would also advice using `visibility_of_element_located` expected condition instead of `presence_of_element_located` to wait for more mature element state, when it becomes visible, not just presented (but may be still not completely rendered).
So your code could be

```py
WebDriverWait(self.driver, self.delay).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class,'buttonstyle')]//span[contains(text(),'Einloggen')]")))
```